# PHP, JS, AJAX can't send value to DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I am making a site with images that can be dragged around. I then have a Javascript code which detects where on the page the user is dragging them by x and y coordinates. For that, I have this code: (house_position.js)

```
    var offset = 0;
```

var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").draggable({
        containment: '#house_wall1',

```
    drag: function(){
        offset = $(this).offset();
        xPos = offset.left;
        yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },

    // Find original position of dragged image.
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Show start dragged position of image.
        var Startpos = $(this).position();
        $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
    },

    // Find position where image is dropped.
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
    }
});
```

});

Besides that, I have a AJAX script that is run by a press on a button. `<button onclick="houseAjax()">Save positions</button>`
That script looks like this:

```
function houseAjax(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        $.post("update_house.php",{newx: xPos, newy: yPos},function(result){
          });
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","update_house.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}
And finally I have update_house.php that is supposed to send the x and y values into a database using prepared statements.

```
  <?php
        require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

        $newX = $_POST['newx'];
    $newY = $_POST['newy'];

    /* Register a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = ?, y = ? WHERE `user_id`=?')) { 

        /* Bind parametres */
        $stmt->bind_param('iii', $newX, $newY, $id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $id = 1;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
            }
?>
```

My problem is that the x and y values doesn't get parsed from JS to PHP correctly somehow. The values does not get into the database and when all this code is run, nothing happens in the database. I know this problem can be in every aspects of the codes above and I hope that it is possible for someone to locate the things that I have not understood correctly. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The database can now insert 0 into the database when the button is pressed, the problem now seems to be something about the javascript variable that tracks the x and y position that doesn't get parsed to the database correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your PHP code, namely the way you are defining the variables and building the query:

```
$newX = $_POST['newx'];
$newY = $_POST['newy'];

/* Register a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = ?, y = ? WHERE `user_id`=?')) { 

    /* Bind parametres */
    $stmt->bind_param('ddi', $newX, $newY, $id);
    ...
```

Comment: Very interesting, it now sends 0 to the database no matter where the image position is, this is going forward. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the answer I wrote up was quick.  You probably want to use floats instead of integers in the query.

Comment: I want to use integers thanks since my database holds integers and there can only be real numbers. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so the next step is to see what values are being passed to your PHP function.

Comment: exactly! I have updated my post and in the bottom of it, it says exactly what I think is the problem now.

Comment: In your houseAjax function, can you set a break point to get the values of xPos and yPos?  Are those variables set globally?

Comment: I don't think they have been set globally, I am not much into Javascript so I was very confused about that part. I don't think the values exist in house_ajax anymore maybe? How can I check this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47888/discussion-between-lnendza-and-user3287771)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have missed to add `$` in front of variable name

```
 $newX = $_POST['newx'];
 $newY = $_POST['newy'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = '".$newX."', y =  '".$newY."' WHERE `user_id`=?')) {
```

Also, `$.post` url should be  `"update_house.php"` instead of `"update_house.php.asp"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm afraid that wasn't enough to solve the problem completely :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$newX = $_POST['newx'];
$newY = $_POST['newy'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = ?, y = ? WHERE `user_id`=?')) { 

/* Bind parametres */
$stmt->bind_param(1, $newX);
$stmt->bind_param(2, $newY);
$stmt->bind_param(3, $id);
```